# WordPress WP_List_Table process_bulk_action method executes twice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

during plugin development I've tried to add product table using WP_List_Table class.
While trying to add custom bulk actions I've discovered that every bulk action executes twice.

I've added

```
$this -> process_bulk_action();
```

to prepare_items method. Removing it results in not executing bulk actions at all.

```
<?php

class BulkPriceEditorTable_init{
    function __construct(){
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this , 'add_admin_menu' ) );
        add_filter( 'set-screen-option' , array( $this , 'set_screen_options' ) , 10, 3);
    }

    public function add_admin_menu(){
        global $bulk_price_editor_page;
        $bulk_price_editor_page = add_menu_page( 
            __( 'Bulk Price Editor' , 'woocommerce-bulk-price-editor' ), 
            __( 'Bulk Price Editor' , 'woocommerce-bulk-price-editor' ),
            'manage_options', 
            'bulk_price_editor', 
            array( $this , 'init' ));

        add_action( "load-$bulk_price_editor_page" , array( $this , 'get_screen_options' ) );
    }

    public function get_screen_options(){...
    }

    public function set_screen_options( $status , $option , $value ){...
    }

    public function init(){
        $table = new BulkPriceEditorTable();
        echo '<div class="wrap"><h2>Bulk Price Editor</h2>';
        echo '<form method="post">';
        $table->prepare_items();
        $table->display();
        echo '</div></form>';
    }
}


class BulkPriceEditorTable extends WP_List_Table{
    private $table_data;

    // Fill the columns with data
    function column_default( $item , $column_name ){
        switch( $column_name ){
            case 'id':
            case 'product_id':
            case 'product_name':
            case 'r_price':
            case 's_price':
            default:
                return $item[$column_name];
        }
    }


    /* data */

    // Get the data for columns
    function get_data(){
        $data = array();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'product',
            'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);...
    
        return $data;
    }
    // Prepare items to display in table
    function prepare_items(){
        $columns    = $this -> get_columns();
        $hidden     = ( is_array( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id() , 'managetoplevel_page_bulk_price_editorcolumnshidden' , true ) ) ) ? get_user_meta( get_current_user_id() , 'managetoplevel_page_bulk_price_editorcolumnshidden' , true ) : array();
        $sortable   = $this -> get_sortable_columns();
        $primary    = 'product_name';
        $screen     = get_current_screen();
        
        $this -> process_bulk_action();

        $this -> table_data         = $this -> get_data();
        $this -> _column_headers    = array( $columns , $hidden , $sortable , $primary );

        usort( $this -> table_data , array( &$this , 'usort_reorder' ) );

        /* pagination */
        $items_per_page = $this -> get_items_per_page( 'elements_per_page' );
        $current_page   = $this -> get_pagenum();
        $total_items    = count( $this -> table_data );

        $this -> table_data = array_slice( $this -> table_data , ( ( $current_page -1 ) * $items_per_page ) , $items_per_page );
        $this->set_pagination_args(
            array(
                'total_items' => $total_items,
                'per_page'    => $items_per_page,
                'total_pages' => ceil( $total_items / $items_per_page ),
            )
        );

        $this -> items = $this -> table_data;
    }
    // Call function to prepare items and display the table
    function display(){
        $this -> prepare_items();
        parent::display();
    }

    /* bulk actions */

    // Get the bulk actions
    function get_bulk_actions(){
        $bulk_actions = array(
            'set_new_price'     => __( 'Set price to' , 'woocommerce-bulk-price-editor' ),
            'multiply_price'    => __( 'Multiply price by' , 'woocommerce-bulk-price-editor' ),
            'modify_price'      => __( 'Modify price by' , 'woocommerce-bulk-price-editor' ),
        );

        return $bulk_actions;
    }
    // Process bulk actions
    function process_bulk_action(){
        new Notices( 'success' , __( 'Working ✔' , 'woocommerce-bulk-price-editor' ) ); 
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to find information about what is happening here and why, and by debugging I have not found a reason why it works this way. Does anyone perhaps have an idea about and solution to this problem

Comment: You call `prepare_items()` in two different places: `init()` and `display()`. I hate when that happens :-)

Comment: Thanks! How did I not see that hah. Which one do you prefer to delete? Does it make any difference?

Comment: Which do I prefer? I'lll answer that question with a question to you: Is preparing these items conceptually a step towards displaying them?  Then prepare them inside the `display` method. Is `display` called from anyplace other than `init`? If so can it assume the items are prepared? If this were my code I'd choose, then write a comment explaining my choice.